# NullPointerException when starting AnimatedVectorDrawable on API 22

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, animatedvectordrawable

I'm using this snippet to start an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` animation:

```
AnimatedVectorDrawable vectorAnim = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) ((ImageView) child).getDrawable();
vectorAnim.start();
```

(Basically I get the `android:src` of the ImageView, which is an `AnimatedVectorDrawable`, and then I launch the animation).

It works fine on every device I tested until now, but when I run my app on an API 22 device I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.isStarted(AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:427)
                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.start(AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:440)
                                                                          at com.brickx.creartup.MainRoadmapAdapter.animateViews(MainRoadmapAdapter.java:263)
                                                                          at com.brickx.creartup.MainRoadmapAdapter.access$100(MainRoadmapAdapter.java:31)
                                                                          at com.brickx.creartup.MainRoadmapAdapter$1.onInflate(MainRoadmapAdapter.java:66)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewStub.inflate(ViewStub.java:284)
                                                                          at com.brickx.creartup.MainRoadmapAdapter.inflateBackground(MainRoadmapAdapter.java:215)
                                                                          at com.brickx.creartup.MainRoadmapAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainRoadmapAdapter.java:71)
                                                                          at com.brickx.creartup.MainRoadmapAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainRoadmapAdapter.java:31)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6519)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5706)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3436)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3988)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:611)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:874)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1172)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
```

Any idea on what is going on here?

**EDIT**

I know what `NullPointerException` means, but sadly I think I have no control over this one. And I can't figure out why this exception is being thrown here...

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal This NPE is being thrown at the Android level, and the asker has no control over how the `AnimatedVectorDrawable` class deals with null pointers. I doubt the answer to the question you have marked as a dupe will help this asker.

Comment: @pushasha Yes I probably shouldn't have written NullPointerException in my title! My bad, but you're right my question was more about where this exception came from rather than its nature.

Comment: @Keysaw I don't have enough information to give you an answer, but I can tell you from [looking at the `AnimatedVectorDrawable` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.java/#427) that the null pointer is referring to to the array of `Animator`s stored within the `AnimatedVectorDrawableState`. Doubt that helps, but if no one else answers, hopefully that gives you something to go on.

Comment: I suggest you create a project where you can consistently reproduce this and file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: @pushasha You're absolutely right. I'm sorry for that. Do you know any possibility to "unflag"? I deleted comment suggesting duplicate but when I look at flags proposed by me, it's still there waiting for review. I would like to save moderators time and delete it as it's irrelevant, but I can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured out the root of the problem! Even if I have no idea how to solve this issue properly.

The crash happens when I try to launch the animation on an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` which has NO `target` attribute (I'm using a [single XML file](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) to define the vector drawable and its animations).

More precisely, I think android looks into the `animated-vector` element and throws an error if no `target` if found. Again, I only encountered this issue on API 22 so far, but I haven't tested other APIs yet...

I can only think of **two solutions** for now:

- either add at least one `target` element into the `AnimatedVectorDrawable`,
- or use a simple `VectorDrawable` if no animation is needed (I used `AnimatedVectorDrawable` regardless whether or not my vector was animated, to be able to easily add animations to it later if I wanted to).

#### EDIT

I found a simple workaround to avoid changing everything, that maybe can help others: I just had to add a dumb `target` to all my `AnimatedVectorDrawable` that shouldn't be animated.

```
<target android:name="vector">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:valueTo="1"/>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
```

That way nothing changes in the `AnimatedVectorDrawable`, but the error is not showing. I don't recommend this though, as it's pretty dirty and can lead to other issues.

Comment: Super strange and funny exception, but in fact if you don't have target in your animated-vector xml element on API Level 22 you will have this crash. Google please fix it, maybe by providing more useful info in the crash! +1 from me

Comment: I have an AnimatedVector which has a target but it still throws a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Found the same issue on API 21 and 22.

The solution that helped me was to define both parameters `android:valueFrom` and `android:valueTo` on `objectAnimator` in xml :

```
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="fillColor"
    android:duration="250"
    android:valueFrom="#393749"
    android:valueTo="#00000000"
    android:valueType="colorType"/>
```

But on API above it's working without `android:valueFrom` (crazy droid does not save our time:)